# Access getter value from another file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently creating a node project, and have created a model like so:

```
export default class Tokens {
    constructor() {
        this.accessToken = '';
        this.refreshToken = '';
    }

    getAccessToken() {
        return this.accessToken;
    }

    setAccessToken(value) {
        this.accessToken = value;
    }

    getRefreshToken() {
        return this.refreshToken;
    }

    setRefreshToken(value) {
        this.refreshToken = value;
    }
};
```

in one file - i have instantiated that class, and set the values like so:

index.js

```
    const token = new Tokens();
    token.setAccessToken(access_token);
    token.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
```

In another file, i am trying to figure out how to access the `getAccessToken` function from the class.

I tried instantiating it again, but its wrong like so:

scheduler.js

```
import Tokens from './models/tokens.js'

const test = new Tokens();
console.log('xxx',test.getAccessToken())
```

I tried calling `this.getAccessToken()`, and it returns undefined.

help?

Comment: What is the relevant code for the other file? Did you import correctly? And by `I tried instantiating it again, but its wrong.` what is the error message showing?

Comment: The question i am asking is how can i call that instance from another file

Comment: @MubeenHussain Do you mean you want to export the instance of the class or the Class definition itself?

Comment: the instance of the class

Comment: You could use the [singleton pattern](https://medium.com/@bretcameron/singletons-in-javascript-59655927b7d7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instanciated a new instance of the class.This is why is it undefined. There is a few way you could fix this problem. I would suggest exporting the created model and using this model in your other file.

```js
//model.js
   const token = new Tokens();
    token.setAccessToken(access_token);
    token.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
    export default token;
 
// scheduler.js
import { test } from './models/model.js'

// Here, the test is going to be the same as declared before.
console.log('xxx',test.getAccessToken())
```

Here, you can see that the newly instanciated class is imported into the `scheduler`, to be used.

Another way you could acheive this is to use a singleton pattern. A singleton is a class that contains only one instance. Using this pattern, the data will be the same whereever you are trying to call the function.

```
export default class TokensSingleton {
    this.instance = null;

    constructor(){ /* ... */}

    static getInstance() {
        if(!TokensSingleton.instance) {
            TokensSingleton.instance = new TokensSingleton();
        }
        
        return TokensSingleton.instance;
    }

    /* ... */
}


//index.js
    const token = TokenSingleton.getInstance();
    token.setAccessToken('test');
    token.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

// scheduler.js
import Tokens from './models/tokens.js'


const test = TokenSingleton.getInstance();
console.log('xxx',test.getAccessToken()) // xxx, test
```

Please note that this code is untested.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try to use natvie class getters and setters for Javascript
See more here https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax

Comment: Using native getter and setter won't affect the multiple instances problem.